# Event when user activates / deactivates Push on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cordova, notifications, push

I'm developing an iPhone & Android via Phonegap. I already got the Push Function to work on the iOS device, and I also can recognise whether the user has Push activated or not while the App is running.
Now I want to be informed when the user activated / deactivated Push Messages in the notification center, even if the app is not running.

Is there anyway to do this? I searched quite a lot on this topic, but all I found were ways to recognise if push is activated or not, which I already can.

Any help will be appreciated.